# How to fix have "Microsoft.VC80.CRT" error during install Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014

How to fix have "Microsoft.VC80.CRT" error during install Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

I have 2 error during install Microsoft SQL Server 2014 below.

```
The following error has occurred:

An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80073712. 

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2430.0&EvtType=0xF45F6601%25401201%25401
```

```
The following error has occurred:

SQL Server Setup has encountered an error when running a Windows Installer file.

Windows Installer error message: An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.CRT,type="win32",version="8.0.50727.6229",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="x86"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. HRESULT: 0x80073712. 
Windows Installer file: C:\Users\508382\Downloads\SSDTBI_x86_ENU\1033_ENU_LP\x86\setup\x86\SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi
Windows Installer log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191106_141241\SQL_AS_OLEDB_Cpu32_1.log

Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=12.0.2430.0&EvtType=0xC24842DB
```

I try fix 2 error with [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1b51a2d8-302c-48d7-bc7f-734a7a032fda/error-installing-sql-server-2014?forum=sqlexpress) but cannot fix 2 error.

Comment: Is the system fully patched using Windows Update?

Comment: @Moab Fully patched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you to introduce , I fix problem with basic solution.

1. Delete .NET Framework with [solution link](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/uninstall-microsoft-net-framework-with-aaron-stebner-cleanup-tool/).
2. Install .NET Framework again with [solution link](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/easily-install-all-versions-of-net-framework-plus-hotfixes-with-aio-runtimes/).
3. Enable .NET Framework 3.5 at Server Manager (in Windows Server 2008 R2 and newer) or Windows Feature (Windows 7 and newer).

If try fix problem with basic solution but not fix problem , I have problem to .NET Framework registry with reference to [link (Thai Language)](http://web.archive.org/web/20110624053027/http://ninkungz.exteen.com/20110621/windows-7) and I have fix problem to clean install Windows again.

Comment: Are you sure you solved this problem by only reinstalling the .NET Framework, because the file in question, wouldn't have been installed by reinstalling the .NET Framework.  `Microsoft.VC80.CRT` belongs to the `Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable` which would only have been reinstalled if you reinstalled Visual Studio 2005 and/or reinstalled `Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable`